# Multiple selected link and showed multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have something like this, but now I want to show multiple div's at same time, ex. I selected 'Div 1' and it show his div, now I click 'Div 2' and I want to stay content of 'Div 1' and show 'Div 2'. Can anyone help?

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
  <a id="showAll" class="btn btn-primary">Wszystkie elementy</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.showSingle').click(function() {
    $('.targetDiv').hide();

    $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).show();
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/42uwvhx4/

Comment: So you just want to show the previous div + new div?

Comment: `$('.targetDiv').hide()` will hide all of them each time.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Yes, I want do this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio but with show content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want a simple toggle. By modifying your example, this is how I accomplished it:

**JS**

```
$('#showAll').click(function() {
    $('.btn').addClass('active');
    $('.targetDiv').show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.showSingle').click(function() {
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
  <a id="showAll" class="btn btn-primary active">Wszystkie elementy</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary active" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary active" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary active" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="showSingle btn btn-primary active" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hescano/42uwvhx4/2/

Notice the use of the [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to accomplish the desired behavior.

Comment: While it's not directly stated, I think this is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the work:

```
$('#showAll').click(function() {
$('.btn').removeClass('active');
$('.targetDiv').show();
$(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('.showSingle').click(function() {
  $('.targetDiv').hide();


  var targetHeight = $(this).attr('data-target');

  $(".targetDiv").each(function(){
    var height = $(this).attr('data-value');
    if(height <= targetHeight){
      $(this).show();
    }


  });

  $('.btn').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

with this html change to the target divs: (I think this is better approach than parsing the id values):

```
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" data-value="1">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" data-value="2">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" data-value="3">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" data-value="4">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use another class that hides elements, then on click remove the class that hides that element. This way when you call `$('.hideClass').hide()` it will not hide all the items, only the remaining un-clicked ones:

```
.hideClass{ display: hidden; }

$('.showSingle').click(function() {
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).removeClass("hideClass");
    $('.hideClass').hide();
    ...
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/42uwvhx4/1/)